# Excluding users from People Picker

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

SharePoint 2010

I recently used the following command to target a specific Active Directory Organizational Unit set of users.

```
stsadm -o setsiteuseraccountdirectorypath -path "OU=My Employees,OU=User Accounts,OU=New Structure,DC=corp,DC=mydomain,DC=net" -url https://mysite
```

This worked well, but soon realized that Contractors are placed in a slightly different OU. Their path looks like: `OU=My Contractors,OU=User Accounts,OU=New Structure,DC=corp,DC=mydomain,DC=net`

I discovered that users in this path could not login to SharePoint.

So my question is, how can I exclude certain paths or include more than one?  My main goal is to avoid including Service Accounts which are located in an OU all their own. Like this: `OU=Service Accounts,OU=User Accounts,OU=New Structure,DC=corp,DC=mydomain,DC=net`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserAccountDirectoryPath` only supports a single value. You can use `peoplepicker-searchadcustomfilter` to create an LDAP filter, though you need to have object attributes to filter from (the `DN` won't be one of the applicable attributes).

[Filter Active Directory accounts by using LDAP queries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server-2010/gg602075(v=office.14)#filter-active-directory-accounts-by-using-ldap-queries)

Comment: Thanks Trevor. I'll look into this. Question, what is "DN" that you mention?

Comment: It is the attribute distinguishedName.